# SSRS Datasource/set Credentials

Tags: ssrs-2008, credentials

I've been recently working on a few projects with SSRS, and noticed when checking shared data source properties there are 2 ways of connecting:

1. Credentials supplied by the user running the report
2. Credentials stored securely in the report server

I am a bit confused the purposes of each connection method. Also I was unable to find any relevant usernames report server database even though the second method says Credentials stored securely in the report server.

Could anyone share some insight please?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

When connecting to a database, you need an athentication method so that the sql server gives you permission to query the sources.

The first method is that when you run the report the report itself will ask for a username and a password to be able to connected to the DB (or it will use your windows identity).

The second method is that the report will automatically connected to the server with the athentication placed in your report server. it will not prompt the user for a username or password. The password is stored in the server and not in the report itself (which is why it is more secured). This is the best method because you don't want every user to type the same username and password to access a report. Unless you have a specific reason to do otherwise I recomend this method.